# Не могу добавить цветную тень или свечение на кнопку в Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Необходимо, чтобы кнопка отбрасывала цветную тень или имела свечение.

`android:elevation` и `translationZ` не работают.

`android:clipToPadding="false"` так же не помогает.
Использую *API 21*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартными средствами не добиться такого. Обратите внимание на сторонние библиотеки. Например :

**Carbon**

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

**Devlight**

https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout